# Removing a server from a broken Failover Cluster in WS08?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

I'm setting up a test environment with Failover Cluster with 2 WS08 "members" in the cluster, however upon renaming one of the servers' hostname it seems to have broken entirely, so I deleted the cluster by force starting it and then destroying it, but when I try to create a new one it still says one server is part of the cluster. Solutions, anyone?

---

while I appreciate the effort, I needed to get on with testing, so I went with the solution to all problems:

format c:\

Comment: try `cluster /cleanup` from command line.

Comment: tried a couple of the cluster commands, they all gave the following error:

System error 1753 has occurred (0x000006d9). There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.

Comment: Oh, and when I do supply the cluster name (which I forgot the first time) I got this error:

System error 1722 has occurred (0x000006ba).
The RPC server is unavailable.

Comment: What does the Cluster Log say? And the event log? What type of output do you get when trying:
cluster /destroy
or if the cluster still exists, what do you get when trying:
cluster node
cluster res
cluster group ??? Also, it would help to post any of the errors from the Cluster Validation Wizard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for future reference, you could have tried to run `cluster/forcecleanup` then deleted any values from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\ClusDisk\Parameters\AttachedDisks`